# Upgrading to Rails 7: Cannot delete objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Okay,

I know there are multiple questions related to this, but none of them seem to help me get any further. Basically my delete links are no longer working, and I'm aware that this is because of the removal of `rails-ujs` in Rails 7, but I simply cannot get them to work.

The application comes from a Rails 6 version, and now runs Rails 7. The following things have been added:

- `hotwire-rails`
- `jsbundling-rails`
- `cssbundling-rails`
- `turbolinks`
- `sprockets-rails`

I've followed all the instructions of the gems by setting up the required steps in my `package.json` so that everything compiles properly when running `assets:precompile` etc. And the application works properly, TailwindCSS and everything gets loaded except I cannot get the delete links to work whatsoever.

I tried the following approaches:

```
.flex.flex.row.pt-5.justify-center
      = form.submit class: "btn-submit"
      - if application.persisted?
        button.btn.btn-red.inline-block
          = button_to 'Destroy', application_path(application), method: :delete
```

```
.flex.flex.row.pt-5.justify-center
      = form.submit class: "btn-submit"
      - if application.persisted?
        button.btn.btn-red.inline-block
          = link_to 'Destroy', application_path(application), data: { turbo_method: :delete }
```

I've tried adding `@rails-ujs` back to the package file, nothing seems to work.
It keeps just doing a GET on the object URL.

How do I get this mess untangled and make delete links again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was not intuitive whatsoever.
I fixed it by adding `@rails/ujs` to my package.json and then adding the following to my `application.js`:

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
Rails.start()
```

Now the deletion and confirmation work again as expected.

Comment: This isn't that stange. You didn't have [turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/) (which is not the same thing as Turbolinks) and you didn't have Rails UJS which provides the functionality that makes links with `method: :delete` magically post a form to send a DELETE request.

Comment: This is the kind stuff that needs to be better documented in Rails upgrades.

Comment: Rails 7 is really a complete paradigm shift when it comes to JS - and its kind of out of scope of the upgrade guide. Its better explained by in [this blog post by DHH](https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b). Basically webpacker is out the door and Turbolinks and Rails UJS have reached the end of their life. If you want to keep using them for legacy compatibility thats fine.

Comment: I'm aware that the paradigm shifted, and trust me I've read the blogs, the upgrade guides, the open issues on GitHub and the pull requests. The amount of hits you get about this DELETE not working tells enough there's an info issue.  Once it works it all makes sense. There should be a guide explaining how you move from "classic" rails 6 to using the `importmaps` or the new `jsbundling-rails`. E,g a caveats section and how to deal with it.